# Why do i get this stack smashing error in my program?

Tags: c, strcpy, string.h

I am practicing my use of strcpy() in C and wrote this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){


   int array[4] = {3,7,1,5};
   char str[4], temp[5];


   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       sprintf(&str[i],"%d", array[i]);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

       strcpy(&temp[i],&str[i]);
       printf("%c", temp[i]);
   }



     return 0;

}
~
```

Unfortunately i get a 'stack smashing' error why is this ?

Comment: Try: `char str[4][10];`. You need multiple string buffers not a single one

Comment: Have you gone straight to practicing it with an array before practicing it with a single string? Now you might have two unknowns to sort out instead of just one.

Comment: It's always best to include the **actual text** of an error that you're asking about. Specific errors have specific reasons, so stating exactly what error you're seeing helps us help you.

Answer (score 1):

[Strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) in C **must** be terminated by a NUL byte (`'\0'`), and you must account for that when you size your buffers.

Given the contents of `array`, the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   sprintf(&str[i], "%d", array[i]);
}
```

will write bytes as follows, remembering that arrays are indexed from `0`:

- `'3'` to the 0th index, `'\0'` to the 1st index
- `'7'` to the 1st index, `'\0'` to the 2nd index
- `'1'` to the 2nd index, `'\0'` to the 3rd index
- `'5'` to the 3rd index, `'\0'` to the 4th index

You write over the previously placed NUL with the current integer. Do you see the problem, though? There is not a 4th index in `str[4]`. You're going to write a byte to memory that you should not be accessing.

---

Even with `str[5]`, so that there is room for the final NUL, the second part of your code would work in a very counter productive way.

The results of the first loop would have the contents of `str` be equal to `"3714"`, such that

```
strcpy(&temp[i], &str[i]);
```

would then copy the strings as such:

- `"3714"` to temp + 0
- `"714"` to temp + 1
- `"14"` to temp + 2
- `"4"` to temp + 3

See how you're just walking along the same string, recopying the same tails to the same locations? `printf("%c", temp[i]);` is just going to print the first character of whichever tail you're on.

With enough room in `str`, this program is essentially a very round about way of writing:

```
int array[] = { 3, 7, 1, 5 };

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%d", array[i]);
```

Additionally, if `array` were to contain any integers whose representation as a string required more than a single byte (e.g., `-5`, `32`), this code would not scale at all.

---

You'll want to change `str` to be a 2d array, containing space for all the strings you will create from the integers in `array`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   int array[4] = {3, 7, 1, 5};
   char str[4][12], temp[12];

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       sprintf(str[i], "%d", array[i]);

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       strcpy(temp, str[i]);
       printf("[%d] %s\n", i, temp);
   }
}
```

though this is still not a very interesting exercise for the use of `strcpy`, seeing as we could just print `str[i]` directly.

Here's an example to play around with of using `strcpy` when searching for the last integer in an array whose string representation is longer than than two characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int array[] = { 3, 7, 123, 4, 13, -55, 29, 55 };

    char string[12] = "0", temp[12];

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof array / sizeof *array); i++)
        if (sprintf(temp, "%d", array[i]) > 2)
            strcpy(string, temp);

    printf("Final value: %s\n", string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `str[i]` can only hold a single character, not a string - when you write

```
sprintf( &str[i], "%d", array[i] );
```

you are attempting to write a 2-character string<sup>1</sup> to a 1-character buffer; the string terminator is "spilling" into the array element `str[i+1]` until you get to `str[3]`, in which case the terminator spills over the end of the array.

To store an array of *strings*, you need to set aside a 2D array of `char`:

```
char str[4][N+1]; // can hold 4 strings of length N, +1 for the string terminator
```

Then in your `sprintf` statement, you'd write

```
sprintf( str[i], "%d", array[i] ); // no & operator on str[i]
```

---

1. All the values in `array` are only one digit - for larger values, you would need more characters in your array.  A string representation of a 32-bit `int` can have up to 10 digit characters, plus a sign character, plus the string terminator, so you need to set aside an array that can hold 12 elements, so ideally `str` should be declared as

   ```
   char str[4][12];
   ```